# Windows Server 2008 Antivirus Software with an API

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, anti-virus

I'm looking for an Antivirus package that is compliant with Windows Server 2008. That's not the hard part. What I need is an API layer on the Antivirus that i can call from managed .net code.

For example:
I am developing an Asp.Net (C#) website that allows users to upload files to the web server which the web site resides on. We have full control of the server so there are no security/rights issues on the server. I need to be able to run the antivirus algorithm on the newly uploaded files without (hopefully) shelling out to a command-ilne version of the software.

Does anyone know of such a package?

Comment: Well most 2008-compatible antivirus solutions already have a real-time file system scanner, so I don't see the point. Forgive me for being blunt.

Comment: lol - because if you want to scan only certain files not every file or exit the supported configuration of xyz antivirus then you need an API. Forgive my late reply and for laughing at your statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any particular reason why shelling out to run an on-demand scan is a bad thing (aside from the additional resource usage of the command prompt)?  Return code management?

Many AV solutions will only do a shallow-depth scan during real-time scanning, but perform a full-depth inspection for an on-demand scan.

Comment: I appologize. I had asked this question in StackOverflow as well and didn't even notice the replies here. This is what I ended up doing as I recall. An API would have been nice to scan files that match this regular expression and ignore other files but I ended up doing the same thing via shelling... e.g. if (match) ShellExecute(specificFile).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Microsoft Forefront Endpoint Protection is fully supported for Windows Server 2008 and also Windows Server 2008 R2:
[Microsoft Forefront Endpoint Protection 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/forefront/endpoint-protection/en/us/default.aspx)

There are not much antivirus vendors who allow you to run managed .net code against, as far as I know.I think you need to reverse engineer the antivirus application to able to do that. But I'm more an sysadmin that an developer, so I could be wrong in this case ;).

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use one of the many AVs that does realtime scanning and has a centralized reporting component? Honestly, anything worth looking at has what you are looking for and doesn't require you to roll your own .net solution.